# html document subdomain webpage

Tags: html, default-document

You can see what I'm talking about in the screenshot below.

Basically, I have a subdomain (i.e. subdomain.website.com) and all I want on it is a single HTML document to display. The HTML document is titled `home.php` in the image but it should be `home.html`, which I'll change later.

When I open `subscribe.website.com` in my browser, I'm presented with the 2nd image, and have to click on the document link to display it. Is there a way to set it up so that when I go to `subscribe.website.com`, `home.html` document loads automatically?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done in multiple ways:

- The simplest way would be to rename your file as `index.html` This is because most web servers are configured by default to server some `default document`'s, of which `index.html` is one, and so is `index.php` if you fancy it.
- Another way is to add `your-page-name.ext` to that list of `default document`'s. But the way to do this is server dependent. You seem to have a Linux host. In which case, you can use the solution provided by [@Ethanh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377141/476786) by adding `DirectoryIndex home.html` to your `.htaccess` file. If this doesn't work, there is the possibility that your host doesn't allow you to edit `.htaccess` files. In this case, you will have to contact your web host.
- If your server was a Windows based machine, you would have had to add the same document name to the [`default document` list](http://blogs.iis.net/nitashav/archive/2010/04/19/iis6-0-ui-vs-iis7-x-ui-series-default-document.aspx) of `IIS`
- There are more ways, each increasing in complexity, which for the level of this answer, I'll keep out.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code in your htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

You can change it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

when the file is in html format it will load the website automatically rather than show you the file in a list